# How do I sequentially extract English text from different web pages of a Tamil website?

Tags: html, parsing, url, html-parsing, html-parser

The Naalayira Divya Prabandham is a 4000-verse collection of Hindu poems written in the Tamil language. The website http://dravidaveda.org has a web page for each of the 4000 verses. Each verse page gives the Tamil verse, a word-by-word Tamil commentary on the verse, and an English translation.  For instance, [here](http://dravidaveda.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1379&ml=1) is the web page for verse 1008.

My question, is there any way I can extract the English translations of all 4000 verses in order, so I can have a complete English translation of the Naalayira Divya Prabandham in a single document? For instance, in the web page I linked to above, I want to extract "Singavel-Kundram is the place where the pure Lord came as a man-lion,-while the world stood awe-struck,-and tore the Asura Hiranya’s chest with his claws. Red eyed lions offer worship by heaping elephant tusks at his feet with reverence." along with the number 1008, and I want to put it in the 1008th place in my document.

So how would I go about doing that? I assume this would this might require some kind of programming, but I don't have much of a technical background, so can someone tell me what I would need to do? Note that the article ID's, for instance the number 1379 in the URL "dravidaveda.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1379&ml=1", don't go sequentially by verse, so that may pose a bit of a problem from a programming standpoint.

Comment: There is no link for the verse 1008.

Comment: @AmbrishPathak Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: Do you know any programming at all? If not, do you want to learn to program for this project?

Comment: from which menu all the verses can be accessed? @KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: @AmbrishPathak That's part of the problem, there is no webpage that has links to all 4000 verse pages.  But if you start at the homepage and scroll down, you'll see a menu with a bunch of green arrows on the right hand side.  If you click one of the options you'll get a bunch of links, and if you click one of those links you'll be taken to a webpage that has links to 10 verses out of the 4000.

Comment: @AmbrishPathak But I find the easiest way to navigate to a specific verse page is through Google searching.  Like to find verse 1008 I just type site:dravidaveda.org 1008

Comment: So, this can be solved in two parts, first part would extract all 4000 links to a excel and then using these links english part can be extracted one by one using vba

Comment: @AmbrishPathak OK, but is there any way to get all 4000 links, short of manually doing it one by one?

Comment: Yes this can be done using vba, search google using site:dravidaveda.org 1008, replace 1008 with loop numbers and extract all the links first, i know it is lengthy process.

Comment: @AmbrishPathak But how would I put a Google search in a loop?  What language can do automated Google searching?

Comment: Search and try using VBA (excel macro), i can provide you with the vba code that can pull english text for 1008th link

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan If you're going to cross-post something, you should note that you've done so and link to the question on other sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with software/commands that dump content of webpages into terminal or console. e.g [`lynx`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29), [`w3m`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3m), [`links`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_%28web_browser%29), etc. (Though it is also possible with `wget`, `curl`, `aria2` etc). Visit manual pages of respective commands for further information.

Here I'm providing sample example by using `lynx`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {47..4568}
 do
 {
 lynx -dump "http://dravidaveda.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=$i&ml=1" | head -n 1 >> ndp.txt
 echo -e "\n" >> ndp.txt
 lynx -dump "http://dravidaveda.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=$i&ml=1" | grep 'English Translation' -A 10 >> ndp.txt
 echo -e "\n\n" >> ndp.txt
 }
 done;
```

Here `{47..4598}` will auto expand into 47,48,....,4568 sequentially. (I've found Nalayira Divya Prabandham can be fetched from this range)

1<sup>st</sup>`lynx` command will write no. of verse e.g (1008) in the file named `npd.txt`

2<sup>nd</sup>`lynx` command will write "English Translation" for that verse in `npd.txt`

Hence, with the help of `for` loop and depending on the range provided, you'll get no. of verses with Engish Translation in the file `npd.txt`.

Note that as you've mentioned that page id doesn't go subsequently, it is difficult to predict the ids to skip while coding. Anyway, I think you'll easily remove those lines from undesirable page ids from `npd.txt` after having it.

However, if you want you can skip dumping of those pages by using verification like:

```
if [[ $(lynx -dump ""http://dravidaveda.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=$i&ml=1" | head -c 1) = "(" ]]
then
[Your commands here]
fi
```

Here expression given in the condition of `if` will check whether first character of page we're going to dump is "(" or not.

So, Following command may work depending on the contents from web pages:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {47..4568}
 do
 {
   if [[ $(lynx -dump "http://dravidaveda.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=$i&ml=1" | head -c 1) = "(" ]]
   then 
     {
     lynx -dump "http://dravidaveda.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=$i&ml=1" | head -n 1 >> ndp.txt
     echo -e "\n" >> ndp.txt
     lynx -dump "http://dravidaveda.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=$i&ml=1" | grep 'English Translation' -A 10 >> ndp.txt
     echo -e "\n\n" >> ndp.txt
     } 
   fi
 }
 done;
```

I've checked and above script runs fine on my PC.

---

Update/Improvement:

The file `ndp.txt` is having verses in non-sequential order since we're getting verses in non-sequential order from website. So, finally it can be sorted with the following command (Thanks to [@terdon](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon) for perl code):

```
perl -ne 'if(/^\((\d+)\)\s*$/){$d=$1;} push @{$k{$d}},$_; END{print "@{$k{$_}}\n" for sort { $a <=> $b} keys(%k)} ' npd.txt
```